# Как заменить все символы между тегами с помощью Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, теги

Мне нужно заменить все символы с - `/` на - `\` между тегами `<tagname>` ... `</tagname>`.

Файл имеет как минимум 10 таких блоков тегов и мне нужно только заменить символ `/` внутри этих тегов.

Как я могу это сделать?

Пробовал с помощью JAXB, но опять же, танцы с бубном...
Остается только регулярка! Но там тоже, "чёрт ногу сломит".

Ведь, как-то же браузер обрабатывает текст между тегами `<code>`...`</code>`, и выделяет, допустим все `(` `)` скобки зеленым а по всему телу html скобки остаются черные.

Comment: более развернутый ответ здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603681/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String startTag = "<tagname>";
    String endTag = "</tagname>";

    String s = "fir/st exa/mple li/ne " + startTag + "fir/st exa/mple li/ne" + endTag
            + "\nsec/ond exa/mple li/ne " + startTag + "sec/ond exa/mple li/ne" + endTag;

    System.out.println("До изменения: \n" + s);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        s = s.replace(matcher.group(0), startTag + matcher.group(1).replace("/", "\\") + endTag);
    }

    System.out.println("\nПосле изменения: \n" + s);
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
До изменения: 
fir/st exa/mple li/ne <tagname>fir/st exa/mple li/ne</tagname>
sec/ond exa/mple li/ne <tagname>sec/ond exa/mple li/ne</tagname>

После изменения: 
fir/st exa/mple li/ne <tagname>fir\st exa\mple li\ne</tagname>
sec/ond exa/mple li/ne <tagname>sec\ond exa\mple li\ne</tagname>
```

Как видно, были заменены символы `/` на `\` находящиеся только между заданными тегами.

Может быть можно решить как-то проще, например, как-то так:

```
s = s.replaceAll(startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag, startTag + "$1".replace("/", "\\") + endTag);
```

но дело в том, что `"$1".replace("/", "\\")` почему-то не отрабатывает.

А, ну и для экономии памяти целесообразно заменить `String` на `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder`.

Comment: Небольшой, хотя как сказать..., конфуз. Если после тега стоит `\n`, то не работает. Пример:`"<pre><code>\n"`

Comment: @Jürgen von Markoff, Попробуйте закрыть теги.

Comment: дело не в тегах. если в абзаце, между тегами попадается хотя бы один `\n`, то... пиши, пропало!

Answer (score 1):

Если условие действительно такое, и теги `<tagname>` ... `</tagname>` не могут быть вложенными, тогда все **"почти"** просто:

```
s/^.*<tagname>.*?(\/).*?<\/tagname>.*$//sg
```

Не знаю, если в Джаве есть оператор (функция) глобальной замены, как в Перле - то оператором/функцией, иначе в цикле.

Написал, "почти" по той причине, что, вероятно между указанными тегами, могут быть и другие закрывающие теги. Тогда совсем-совсем не просто. Пример, пусть есть подстрока:

`<tagname>Это пример <sub>непростой</sub> строки<img src="http://host.com/pic.gif"></tagname>`

По условию вопроса строка примет вид:

`<tagname>Это пример <sub>непростой<\sub> строки<img src="http:\\host.com\pic.gif"></tagname>`

А это совсем не корректно.

В общем случае нужно строить [AST](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii_sWOzPHQAhVG2SwKHciAAygQFgggMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%2590%25D0%25B1%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BA%25D1%2582%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B5_%25D1%2581%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D1%2582%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BA%25D1%2581%25D0%25B8%25D1%2587%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B5_%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D0%25B5%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BE&usg=AFQjCNFNp_PJCJefSqPQ4d2rKwd--947Lg&sig2=7jfx8TWIcWCLSXiFy9Lpcg) и уже "бегать с заменами" по нему. Это решает проблему, за одно проверяется и корректность разметки.